# Why is my vectorized smoothing function slower?

Tags: c++, vectorization, sse, smoothing

I have written two version of a smoothing function which takes applies a kernel to the output of 9 coordinates.

```
float PerlinHeightMapGenerator::defaultSmooth(int x, int z, const float kernel[9])
{
    const float top = defaultNoise(x - 1, z + 1) * kernel[0] + defaultNoise(x, z + 1) * kernel[1] + defaultNoise(x + 1, z + 1) * kernel[2];
    const float middle = defaultNoise(x - 1, z) * kernel[3] + defaultNoise(x, z) * kernel[4] + defaultNoise(x + 1, z) * kernel[5];
    const float bottom = defaultNoise(x - 1, z - 1) * kernel[6] + defaultNoise(x, z - 1) * kernel[7] + defaultNoise(x + 1, z - 1) * kernel[8];

    const float total = (top + middle + bottom);

    return total;
}

float PerlinHeightMapGenerator::defaultSmooth(int x, int z, const XMVECTOR kernel[3])
{
    const XMVECTOR top = XMVector3Dot(XMVectorSet(defaultNoise(x - 1, z + 1), defaultNoise(x, z + 1), defaultNoise(x + 1, z+ 1), 0), kernel[0]);
    const XMVECTOR middle = XMVector3Dot(XMVectorSet(defaultNoise(x - 1, z), defaultNoise(x, z), defaultNoise(x + 1, z), 0), kernel[1]);
    const XMVECTOR bottom = XMVector3Dot(XMVectorSet(defaultNoise(x - 1, z - 1), defaultNoise(x, z - 1), defaultNoise(x + 1, z - 1), 0), kernel[2]);

    XMFLOAT4 answer;
    XMStoreFloat4(&answer, XMVectorAdd(top, XMVectorAdd(middle, bottom)));
    return answer.x;

}
```

The second version uses vector instructions, but for the input I am using is significantly slower (adds almost 200 milliseconds to the total execution time for the entire program).  Shouldn't the vectorized version be faster since it can call "defaultNoise" three at a time, and can also do the multiplications at the same time?

If it's relevant, "defaultNoise(x,z)" does this:

```
float PerlinHeightMapGenerator::defaultNoise(int x, int z)
{
    int n = x + z * 57;
    n = (n<<13) ^ n;
    return static_cast<float>( 1.0f - ( (n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 0x7fffffff) / 1073741824.0f); 
};
```

EDIT:  I have tried some more tests with results I don't understand.
First, I tried changing it so the vectorized function takes an array of 9 floats and then copies them to vectors in the function; does nothing.

I then tried changing the code to see what happens if none of the kernel vectors are actually used.  First, replacing all instances of kernel to XMVectorSet(1, 2, 3, 4) so the code is:

```
const XMVECTOR top = XMVector3Dot(XMVectorSet(defaultNoise(x - 1, z + 1), defaultNoise(x, z + 1), defaultNoise(x + 1, z+ 1), 0), XMVectorSet(1, 2, 3, 4));
    const XMVECTOR middle = XMVector3Dot(XMVectorSet(defaultNoise(x - 1, z), defaultNoise(x, z), defaultNoise(x + 1, z), 0), XMVectorSet(1, 2, 3, 4));
    const XMVECTOR bottom = XMVector3Dot(XMVectorSet(defaultNoise(x - 1, z - 1), defaultNoise(x, z - 1), defaultNoise(x + 1, z - 1), 0), XMVectorSet(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

This cut the execution time of the program from 4 seconds to less than 2 seconds (50% reduction).

I then tried replacing the first XMVectorSet(1, 2, 3, 4) back with kernel[0], and this increased the execution time to about 2100 milliseconds.  Replacing the second XMVectorSet(1, 2, 3, 4) with kernel[1] increased the time to 2700 milliseconds;  replacing the final, third vector brought the time back up to 4 seconds.

I tried also copying the floats to the vectors inside the function instead of before it is called, and the result is the same.

EDIT 2:  It appears XMVectorSet(1, 2, 3, 4) is a special case.   Maybe it's faster because it's 4 ints; replacing it with XMVectorSet(.0357143f, 0.0714286f, 0.0357143f, 0) slows it back down to the original speed.

I still don't understand why the vectorized version is slower, though.

Comment: What compiler and compiler options are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012 (update 2) with (as far as I know) every optimization setting activated.  It's targeted to x64.

Comment: Sadly, since I have a Linux system, not sure I can offer much help on the compiler settings. But I can certainly say it will be hard to parallelise the "defaultNoise" - unless you can split it up/rearrange it in some way, that gives more parallel calculations - perhaps you can feed a vector into a defaultNoise like function that gives a vector back out?

Comment: I don't think defaultNoise needs to be parallellized.  I just wanted to run the separate calls to defaultNoise in parallel, since their outcomes are not dependent until they are added.  The defaultNoise calls are each a separate component of XMVectorSet which (to my knowledge) should execute each component in parallel.

Comment: What happens when you increase your array size? Three elements might be too small and you can be only seeing the overhead for aligning your elements for vector operations.

Can you look at the assembly and see how many copy instructions you have?

Also, the defaultNoise() call will probably not be parallelized; it's too complex for vectorization.

Comment: Yeah, but that assumes the compiler can figure out how to achieve that, and I've not had much success with compilers doing that sort of thing. For the vectorisation to help (much), you need as much as possible to be done in each SIMD instructions. So if you can execute several of the "defaultnoise" steps in parallel (say 3 or 4), then that would help a whole lot - at least I think so. As a rough comparison, what is the time if you replace (some/all of) the defaultNoise calculation with a single float value?

Comment: I posted some clarification as an edit with some followup tests -- also, my understanding is that the entire purpose of XMVECTOR is that they are just wrappers for the SSE compiler intrinsics and translate directly to parallel execution.  I don't think the compiler has to figure anything out.